# Scripted install of Sun Java JDK on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, java, ubuntu-9.04, automated-install

We are trying to script the install of the sun jdk on Ubuntu 9.04 and have it automatically accept the license agreement. I have seen something around the net about creating a file that the package looks for, but none of them were complete. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sun Java packages keep track of whether you've agreed to the license agreement using Debconf. You can bypass that check by running

```
echo "sun-java6-bin shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1 boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
```

before installing `sun-java6-jre` or whatever Sun Java package you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this in ubuntu 10.04 and works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh

DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

echo "sun-java6-bin shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1 boolean true" | debconf-set-selections

echo "sun-java6-jre shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1 boolean true" | debconf-set-selections

apt-get install -y sun-java6-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is using a package for your native distribution, as Java is compiled anyway there is not much advantage unless you need a very particular version.  If that were the case, you could also create your own package.

I typically redirect STDIN.  For example:

```
/command/to/run <<_EOF
answer1
answer2
_EOF
```

For particularly tricky things an alternative to that is [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).